# Why CPLEX cannot solve a model that YALMIP can solve using CPLEX?

Tags: cplex

I used YALMIP for modelling, and then saved this model to a .lp file. But I noticed that there was a model that can be solved when YALMIP used CPLEX as a solver, but (.lp file) cannot be solved when I directly used CPLEX. It showed "infeasible", and "Row xxx infeasible, all entries at implied bounds." Why could it happen?

Comment: You can loose precision when exporting to LP file format. Can you try exporting to SAV format instead?

Comment: This sounds similar to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479632.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I spent two days for it and I FINALLY found out the reason.

NOTE THAT when YALMIP defines the decision variables, the lower bound is -infinity by default. However, a model file (.lp, .mps, etc.) used in solvers (gurobi, cplex, etc.) will NOT reflect it. That's why a model built by YALMIP can be infeasible when solved directly by solvers.